# I am trying to send a mail using php, but after clicking the send button the page is blank and no error..i dont know why

Tags: php, email, contact-form

/*Below is the form design */
/*The form is very simple it has only four fields*/
/*I am trying to send a mail using php, but after clicking the send button the page is blank and no error..i dont know why*/

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 m-auto">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-title">
                        <h2 class="text-center py-2">Contact Form</h2>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                        $message = '';
                        if( isset($_GET['error']))
                        {
                            $message = "Please fill the form completely..";
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$message.' </div>';
                        }

                        if( isset($_GET['success']))
                        {
                            $message = "sent successfully";
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.$message.' </div>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="process.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control mb-2">
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control mb-2">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control mb-2">
                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message Here" class="form-control mb-2"></textarea>
                            <button class="btn btn-success " name="btn-send" >Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


/*Process.php script is below*/
```

/* I dont know where it went wrong*/
/* I'm just using a simple mail function in php*/

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['btn-send'])) 
{
    $name = $_POST['userName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


    if( empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message) )
    {
        header('Location: index.php?error');
    }

    else
    {
        $to = 'info@domainname.com';
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $email))
        {
            header('Location: index.php?success');
        }
    }

}

else
{
    header('Location:index.php');
}

?>
```